# parameter transferring in the wmi

Tags: python, wmi

hello everyone I have some problem with understanding this piece of the code:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

process_id, return_value = c.Win32_Process.Create (CommandLine="notepad.exe")
for process in c.Win32_Process (ProcessId=process_id):
  print process.ProcessId, process.Name

result = process.Terminate ()
```

I can't understand

```
(CommandLine="notepad.exe")
```

how exactly this mechanism is working? and where can I find definition of the `CommandLine`
thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sent as part of `**kwargs` of  `def new (self, **kwargs):` as you can see in the [wmi.py](http://svn.timgolden.me.uk/wmi/trunk/wmi.py). The convention is always what Microsoft has defined for the process creation and you can find that in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).